# Generic Respository Pattern with Unit of Work for tables in Relationship

Tags: model-view-controller, unit-of-work

As per my knowledge, Unit Of Work saves all the Repositories in the Pipeline and pushes later as one Database transaction. As per my below scenario.

```
  public class Customer
  {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
  }

  public class Order
  {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Customer")]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PaymentMode")]
    public int PayModeId { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public PaymentMode PaymentMode { get; set; }
  }



  public class OrderProducts
  {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Order")]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Products")]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public Order Order { get; set; }
    public Products Products { get; set; }
  }

 public class DeliveryTrack
 {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Order")]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DeliveryStatus")]
    public int DelStatusId { get; set; }
    public float TotalAmount { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public Order Order { get; set; }
    public DeliveryStatus DeliveryStatus { get; set; }
  }
```

Class `Order`, is referenced by `OrderProducts` and `DeliveryTrack`
   In the DB records are not inserting for `OrderProducts` but it is inserting for `DeliveryTrack`. If `DeliveryTrack` is excluded and if i rather say

```
ObjUow.GetRepository<OrderProducts>().Insert(objOrderProducts);
ObjUow.Save();
```

it's working. Is there any problem with `Order` being refernced by 2 Entities.

Please help.

```
 public int AddOrderDetailsOms(CustomerDto customerDto,PaymentModeDto
 paymentDto, OrderProductsDto orderProductsDto)          
 {
   using (var dbContextTransaction = ObjUow.BeginDataTransaction())
   {
     try
    {
        Customer objCustomer = new Customer
        {
            //  CustomerId = customerDto.CustomerId,
            Name = customerDto.Name,
            Address = customerDto.Address,
            PhoneNumber = customerDto.PhoneNumber,
            IsActive = true
        };

        Order objOrder = new Order
        {
            OrderDate = DateTime.Now,
            IsActive = true,
            PayModeId = paymentDto.Id,
            Customer = objCustomer
        };



        if (orderProductsDto != null)
        {
            foreach (var prodId in orderProductsDto.ProductId)
            {
                OrderProducts objOrderProducts = new OrderProducts
                {
                    // OrderId = orderId,
                    ProductId = prodId,
                    Quantity = 1,
                    Order = objOrder
                };

            }
        }

        DeliveryTrack objDeliveryTrack = new DeliveryTrack
        {
            // OrderId = orderId,
            DelStatusId = 1,
            TotalAmount = 120.00f,
            Order = objOrder
        };

        ObjUow.GetRepository<DeliveryTrack>().Insert(objDeliveryTrack);
        ObjUow.Save();

        dbContextTransaction.Commit();
        return 1;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        dbContextTransaction.Rollback();
        throw ex;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to Insert the Customer first. All you should need to do is create the customer and add the customer to the order, then insert the order. So something like this should work:

```
Customer objCustomer = new Customer
{
    CustomerId = customerDto.CustomerId,
    Name = customerDto.Name,
    Address = customerDto.Address,
    PhoneNumber = customerDto.PhoneNumber,
    IsActive = true
};

Order objOrder = new Order
{
    OrderDate = DateTime.Now,
    IsActive = true,
    PayModeId = paymentDto.Id,
    Customer = objCustomer 
};
ObjUow.GetRepository<Order>().Insert(objOrder);
ObjUow.Save();
```

Comment: That's great, garethb, Thank you so much, it's working perfectly well.

Comment: FYI, I'm guessing your repository Insert() calls DBContext.Add(), the Add() method will update your entire object graph correctly and in correct order. So you can do the same for payment as well. If you go the other way, and add a list of orders to a customer and insert the customer, it will still work.

Comment: Thanks for the info garethb, i will check on that. Please do help me out in terms of bottlenecks.

Comment: Hi garethb, i have made necessary edits as per you said. I extended my requirement to 2 more classes 'Order Products' and 'Delivery Track', i have mentioned the problem i am facing, can you please help me.

Comment: You're inserting into DeliveryTrack, but in this case you will also need to insert into OrderProducts. DeliveryTrack and OrderProducts are not directly related (no foreign key from one to the other). In this case, you should do 2 inserts. Although what I would do is add DeliveryTrack and OrderProducts to the order first then insert an Order. It also looks like the relationship between Order and OrderProducts should be on-to-many?